# How can I extend an image, so that it still works? When can an image be in the from line in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I have a sshd Dockerfile. It works. I can ssh to it. I called the image `local/c7-sshd`.

```
from centos:7
...
expose 22
cmd ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

Now I want to extend this image to a httpd image. I have a Dockerfile,

```
from local/c7-sshd
...
expose 80
cmd ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

When I start a container from this image, httpd runs, but sshd not.

So I do not know when or not an image can be after `from` in a Dockerfile.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: supervisord is like systemd, but this is not what i meant. I would like to know how to extend an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have correctly "extended" the c7-sshd image. The problem is that the `CMD` instruction in the httpd image replaces the `CMD` instruction from the c7-sshd image, so only httpd is being started, not sshd. Every image can only have a single `CMD` instruction which is run when the container is started.

What you need to do is change the `CMD` instruction so that it launches both httpd and sshd. The best way to do this using a process manager as suggested by Mark O'Connor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/.

Also, it's generally better to do this in a script called from an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction rather than `CMD`, so that you can use `CMD` to provide arguments at run-time to the `ENTRYPOINT` script.

Finally, do you actually need sshd? You might find using `docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash` is a better solution.